# What causes a Windows Installer package to require Shell Folders Personal to be a valid location

Tags: windows-installer

Say I have 'My Documents' redirected to H:\, and H: drive is not currently mapped.

Most MSI packages install successfully in this circumstance.

But some MSI packages get Error 1327 Invalid Drive H:.  It's not like the program needs to install something to the home drive.

Every time I've seen Error 1327, it's that specific shell folder - My Documents / Personal.

Does anyone know what is it about a package that makes it check the location that 'My Documents' is redirected to, and other packages to ignore it?

I've opened up one MSI package that fails this way, but can't find any references to Personal or Documents inside it, and it's definitely not the Target folder for any files.  The vendor of this package says that it's a Windows behaviour, but it doesn't happen for all MSI packages, so I think it has to be something about the package that makes Windows Installer look for that folder...

(Please, I don't want answers about whether using a drive letter for a folder redirect is a good idea or not, or how to resolve Error 1327.  I just want to understand about Windows Installer behaviour.)

Thanks,
Sandra

Comment: How is resolving error 1327 mutually exclusive with understanding Windows Installer behavior?  As this isn't your MSI and you aren't the developer, this is off topic.  Vote for move to superuser.

Comment: As I also create MSI packages from time to time, I want to know what to avoid so that mine isn't one of those packages that exhibits this behaviour.  Also, if it's something that's in the vendor's package that doesn't need to be there, I can work with the vendor to see if they would resolve it for me in a future release.  I already know how to work around it, and that has been answered many other places, so that's why it's mutually exclusive from trying to understand Windows Installer behaviour behind it.

Comment: I would suggest reading up on the Directory table and "costing" especially CostFinalize.  Also properties such as ProgramFilesFolder and PersonalFolder.

Comment: If this is a complaint about Windows Installer, take it to Microsoft or read this support article to fix it: http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/327763 One reason for intermittent behavior might be that some installs are per machine, others per user. Note that there is no such thing as a H drve for the system because those mapped drivers are only in the user profile.

Comment: Christopher, thanks for that insight.  I don't see a reference to PersonalFolder in the Directory table, but will read into Costing and CostFinalize.  Not sure why you suggest ProgramFilesFolder - that's on c: drive not not the user's home drive.  Thank you.

Comment: Phil, this is not a complaint about Windows Installer, as I said, I'm not looking for a way to resolve the error.  But it is a wish to understand what in the MSI makes it even look for the location where Personal points to.